# Как лучше написать код приложения для выборки данных по многим ID из базы?

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, .net, entity-framework

К примеру есть массив ID с количеством элементов в диапазоне 10-1M . Как лучше всего из кода c# организовать выборку всех записей из таблицы соответствующих идентификаторам. Подходов может быть много и хотелось бы понимать +- и зависит ли выбор метода от обьема элементов в массиве.

Базы могут быть разные и инструменты на стороне кода тоже, поэтому любой ответ может быть полезен. Но для простоты вопроса можно представить что используем EF и MS SQL Server (это будет предпочтительным ответом).

Сейчас вспомню такие подходы: (1) последовательно отдельным запросом запрашивать оп одному ID, но это много запросов (2) на стороне кода собрать запрос с SQL оператором `IN` ([тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318405/equivalent-in-operator-in-entity-framework?rq=1) или [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137921/how-to-do-an-in-query-in-entity-framework) пример для EF).

Comment: Создать временную таблицу, в памяти, индексированную. Слить туда список. Использовать для отбора.

Comment: Лучше оформить как ответ. Как я понял - сначала это отдельный запрос raw sql для создания временной таблицы (в ef такого не помню), а потом из кода снова делаем raw запрос для выборки, так как таблица временная и в моделях у нас ее нет? Запрос будет содержать Join между временной и целевой таблицами?

Comment: Да нет проблем, ща...

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что оператор Contains как раз подойдёт вам для этих целей.

Примерно вот такой код:

```
        var ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        var result = _context.Set<Entity>()
            .Where(_ => ids.Contains(_.Id))
            .ToListAsync();
```

Стоит только учесть, что если количество идентификаторов будет действительно очень большим, то есть вероятность,того что запрос отвалится по таймауту.
Поэтому имеет смысл разбивать один такой запрос на несколько кусков и потом склеивать результат уже на клиенте.

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, то будет сгенерирован SQL оператор IN из Contains

Comment: А возможно ли подружить linq к материализованной коллекции (такой как ids), и EF? Например, если это не массив с int'ами, а какие-то сопутствующие данные?

Answer (score 2):

Если количество значений в списке велико (ориентировочно - более тысячи), то можно так:

1. Создаём временную таблицу.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_criteria (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE = Memory;
```

Тип данных - откорректировать в соответствии с типом данных поля рабочей таблицы.

Для 1М записей размер таблицы в памяти составит приблизительно 10-11 Мбайт. В то же время её обработка не потребует выполнения медленных операций обращения к диску.

Опять же не надо заботиться и подчищать - как только соединение будет закрыто, таблица тут же самоудалится. Но до закрытия соединения её и вставленные в неё данные можно использовать повторно.

2. Вставить в эту таблицу записи со значениями идентификаторов, подлежащих обработке.

Поскольку таблица - в памяти, скорость вставки будет весьма высокой. К тому же можно вставлять не сразу все значения, а делать это блоками, скажем, по 10к значений - это позволит не наткнуться на ограничение размера входящего пакета и таймаут обработки запроса, плюс снизить влияние вставки на производительность параллельно выполняемых задач.

3. Выполнить выборку, используя данные из временной таблицы. Ну то есть тривиальное

```sql
SELECT id
FROM working_table t1
JOIN tmp_criteria t2 USING (id);
```

Поскольку набор во временной таблице индексированный, должно работать быстро. А если ещё и поле в рабочей таблице индексировано, вообще должно взлететь.

---

В любом случае желательно выполнить сравнение скорости выполнения запроса WHERE IN и описанного способа на реальных системе и данных при разной длине списка, и найти приблизительное количество значений в списке, после которых наблюдается выигрыш по времени и/или иным ресурсам. И если количество значений в списке меньше этого порога - то выполнять получение данных единым запросом WHERE IN.

---

Ну а как это всё перевести с чистого SQL на EF - это не ко мне вопрос.